# What is difference between is_empty and is_empty() in Single Linked List in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, singly-linked-list

i have created Single Linked List in python and i want to know what '()' mainly functions in *def delete_front(self)*.

Here is my Code.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class SLinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0
    
    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def is_empty(self):
        if self.size==0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def search(self,target):
        return 

    def insert_front(self, data):
        nw_node = Node(data)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = nw_node
        else:
            nw_node.next = self.head.next
            self.head.next = nw_node
    #p is pointer
    def insert_after(self, data, p):
        nw_node = Node(data)
        if p==self.size:
            p.next = nw_node
        else:
            nw_node.next = p.next
            p.next = nw_node

    def delete_front(self):
        if is_empty():
            return None
        else:
            tmp_node =self.head.next
            tmp_node.prev = self.head
            self.head.next = tmp_node.next

    def delete_after(self, p):
        if p==self.size:
            return None
        else:
            tmp_node = p.next
            p.next = tmp_node.next

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            print(node)
            node = node.next
```

Comment: Do you mean, what is the difference between `self.is_empty()` and `is_empty()`,  and why do you get an error on the latter?

Comment: Precisely, I want to ask the function '()'.

Comment: `function()` calls `function` with no arguments